# Using Easydropdown with ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to use [patrickkunka/easydropdown](https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown) with the Angular directive ngOptions / ng-options without using jQuery etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't be able to use the easydropdown jquery plugin without JQuery.  It [relies on JQuery](https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown/blob/master/src/jquery.easydropdown.js).